# How to check PDF corrupted or not in Java 1.6, and move corrupted PDF to some folder

Tags: java-6

i want to check PDF corrupted or not before moving to destination folder from source folder. if corrupted i have to move to some different (corrupted) folder.

I am using below code, it is working fine for pdf not corrupted files but if files is corrupted  i can't move pdf to another folder.

Please help me why i cant move pdf file if corrupted, even i closed pdfreader.

```
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(srcPdfFilePath);               
            if (reader != null){
                n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
                if (n > 0) {
                    pdfStatus = true;
                } else {
                    pdfStatus = false;
                }
            }
            else {                  
                pdfStatus = false;
            }
            finally{
                reader.close();
            }

            if (pdfStatus) {
            MoveFile(srcPdfFilePath, destPdfFilePath);

        } else {
            MoveFile(srcPdfFilePath, errorPdfFilePath);

        }

        to move file i am using.

        MoveFile (String oldFile, String newFile)
        if(oldFile.renameTo(newFile))
```